# HighStocks annotation on multiple y-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've a multi y-axis graph in highstocks, and I need to add an annotation to each of the y-axis.

Link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7n5eaqtg/1/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/stocktools/gui.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/annotations/popup.css"
    />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/indicators/indicators-all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/drag-panes.js"></script>

    <script src="annotations-advanced.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/price-indicator.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/full-screen.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/stock-tools.src.js"></script>

    <style>
      .chart:-webkit-full-screen {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .chart:-moz-full-screen {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .chart:-ms-fullscreen {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .chart:fullscreen {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      /* GENERAL */

      .chart {
        float: left;
        max-height: 800px;
        height: 75vh;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .highcharts-draw-mode {
        cursor: crosshair;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" class="chart"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var qrs = [];
    var hr = [];
    var imp = [];
    var res = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
      qrs.push(0);
      qrs.push(0);
      qrs.push(0);
      qrs.push(0);
      qrs.push(0);
      qrs.push(-0.5);
      qrs.push(0.5);
      qrs.push(-0.5);
      qrs.push(0.5);
      qrs.push(-0.5);
      qrs.push(5);
      qrs.push(-3);
      qrs.push(0);
    }

    hr = [
      138,
      138,
      138,
      137,
      137,
      136,
      136,
      136,
      135,
      135,
      135,
      134,
      134,
      133,
      132,
      131,
      130,
      130,
      130,
      130,
      129,
      129,
      129,
      128,
      128,
      127,
      126,
      125,
      124,
      122,
      122,
      121,
      121,
      120,
      120,
      120,
      120,
      119,
      119,
      119,
      119,
      118,
      117,
      116,
      115,
      115,
      114,
      114,
      113,
      112,
      111,
      110,
      109,
      108,
      107,
      106,
      105,
      105,
      103,
      102,
      103,
      104,
      105,
      106,
      107,
      108,
      109,
      110,
      111,
      112,
      113,
      114,
      115,
      116,
      117,
      118,
      119,
      120,
      121,
      125,
      128,
      135,
      140,
      145,
      150,
      155,
      160,
      165,
      170,
      175,
      180,
      190,
      195,
      200,
      210,
      220,
      220,
      230,
      231,
      232,
      233,
      234,
      235,
      236,
      237,
      238,
      239,
      239,
      239,
      238,
      237,
      237,
      235,
      234,
      233,
      230,
      225,
      220,
      215,
      210,
      205,
      200,
      195,
      194,
      194,
      190,
      185,
      180,
      175,
      170,
      165,
      160,
      155,
      150,
      145,
      140,
      135,
      130,
      125,
      120,
      114,
      114,
      113,
      113,
      112,
      111,
      111,
      111,
      111,
      110,
      110,
      110,
      110,
      109,
      109,
      109,
      109,
      108,
      107,
      107,
      107,
      107,
      105,
      105,
      104,
      104,
      104,
      104,
      104,
      104,
      104,
      104,
      104,
      104,
      104,
      104,
    ];

    imp = [
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
      0.3,
      0.2,
    ];

    res = [
      52,
      52,
      51,
      51,
      51,
      50,
      50,
      50,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      48,
      47,
      46,
      46,
      45,
      45,
      43,
      42,
      42,
      41,
      41,
      40,
      40,
      40,
      40,
      39,
      38,
      37,
      36,
      35,
      34,
      33,
      32,
      31,
      31,
      31,
      31,
      30,
      31,
      31,
      31,
      31,
      31,
      31,
      31,
      31,
      31,
      32,
      32,
      32,
      32,
      32,
      32,
      32,
      32,
      33,
      33,
      33,
      33,
      34,
      34,
      34,
      34,
      34,
      34,
      35,
      35,
      35,
      35,
      35,
      35,
      35,
      35,
      35,
      35,
      36,
      36,
      36,
      36,
      36,
      36,
      36,
      36,
      36,
      37,
      37,
      37,
      37,
      37,
      37,
      37,
      37,
      37,
      37,
      38,
      38,
      38,
      38,
      38,
      38,
      38,
      38,
      39,
      39,
      39,
      39,
      39,
      39,
      40,
      40,
      40,
      40,
      40,
      40,
      40,
      40,
      41,
      41,
      41,
      41,
      41,
      41,
      41,
      42,
      42,
      42,
      42,
      42,
      42,
      43,
      43,
      43,
      43,
      43,
      43,
      43,
      43,
      44,
      43,
      43,
      43,
      43,
      43,
      44,
      44,
      44,
      44,
      44,
      44,
      45,
      45,
      45,
      45,
      45,
      45,
      45,
      45,
      46,
      46,
      46,
      46,
      46,
      47,
      47,
      47,
      47,
      47,
      48,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
      49,
    ];

    chartOptions = {
      yAxis: [
        {
          marker: {
            enabled: false,
          },

          name: "QRS",
          color: "#ff0000",
          height: "25%",
          resize: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          min: -10,
          max: 10,
          labels: {
            enabled: false,
          },
        },
        {
          marker: {
            enabled: false,
          },

          name: "HR",
          color: "#034d00",
          top: "25%",
          height: "25%",
          resize: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          min: 0,
          max: 300,
          showEmpty: false,
          labels: {
            enabled: true,
            align: "left",
          },
          plotLines: [
            {
              color: "red", // Color value
              dashStyle: "longdashdot", // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
              value: 100, // Value of where the line will appear
              width: 1, // Width of the line
            },
            {
              color: "red", // Color value
              dashStyle: "longdashdot", // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
              value: 250, // Value of where the line will appear
              width: 1, // Width of the line
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          marker: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          yAxis: 2,
          name: "Impedence",
          color: "#001aff",
          top: "50%",
          height: "25%",
          resize: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          min: -2,
          max: 2,
          labels: {
            enabled: false,
          },
        },
        {
          marker: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          yAxis: 3,
          name: "Resp. Rate",
          color: "#ff002f",
          top: "75%",
          height: "25%",
          resize: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
        },
      ],
      series: [
        {
          type: "line",
          id: "qrs",
          name: "QRS",
          data: qrs,
          yAxis: 0,
          color: "#ff0000",
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          id: "hr",
          name: "HR",
          data: hr,
          yAxis: 1,
          color: "#008000",
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          id: "imp",
          name: "Imp",
          data: imp,
          yAxis: 2,
          color: "#0000FF",
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          id: "res",
          name: "Res",
          data: res,
          yAxis: 3,
          color: "#008000",
        },
      ],
      tooltip: {
        //shared: true,
        crosshairs: true,
        shape: "square",
        headerShape: "callout",
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        positioner: function (width, height, point) {
          var chart = this.chart,
            position;

          if (point.isHeader) {
            position = {
              x: Math.max(
                // Left side limit
                chart.plotLeft,
                Math.min(
                  point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - width / 2,
                  // Right side limit
                  chart.chartWidth - width - chart.marginRight
                )
              ),
              y: point.plotY,
            };
          } else {
            position = {
              x: point.series.chart.plotLeft,
              y: point.series.yAxis.top - chart.plotTop,
            };
          }

          return position;
        },
        pointFormatter: function () {
          var tooltip = null;
          var state = this.series.name == "HR" || this.series.name == "Res";
          if (state) {
            tooltip =
              '<span style="color:' +
              this.color +
              '">\u25CF</span> ' +
              this.series.name +
              ": <b>" +
              this.y +
              "</b><br/>";
          }

          return tooltip;
        },
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: true,
      },

      responsive: {
        rules: [
          {
            condition: {
              maxWidth: 800,
            },
            chartOptions: {
              rangeSelector: {
                inputEnabled: false,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      annotations: [
        {
          langKey: "measure",
          type: "measure",
          typeOptions: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            selectType: "x",
            point: {
              x: 5.040849673202615,
              y: 0,
            },

            crosshairX: {
              strokeWidth: 1,
              stroke: "#000000",
              enabled: false,
            },
            crosshairY: {
              enabled: false,
              strokeWidth: 0,
              stroke: "#000000",
            },
            background: {
              width: 10,
              height: 0,
              strokeWidth: 0,
              stroke: "#ffffff",
            },
          },
          labelOptions: {
            style: {
              color: "#666666",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    };

    Highcharts.stockChart("container", chartOptions);
  </script>
</html>
```

You can see the annotation on the first y-axis, my goal is to create one for each of the y-axis.
The annotation needs to have the functionality of "measure x" annotation, such that it can display the min/max label and be draggable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this issue, it seems like a bug to me. I reported it on Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread and ask the core developers for the workaround. Link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13664

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you for guiding me.